# Как сделать множественный SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть алгоритм выборки из базы данных информации о ценах на различные направления. Выполняется он так: есть город отправки и 12 городов направления; прохожу `foreach`ем по 12 городам и каждый раз инициирую обращение к базе, где делаю запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets_cache WHERE origin = 'Moscow' AND destination = 'Saint-Petersburg';
```

И так 6-12 раз (для успешного завершения нужна информация как минимум о 6 направлениях. Как только собирается информация о всех 6 городах, то выполнение скрипта прерывается для экономии трафика и ресурсов сервера). Хочу оптимизировать эти запросы так, чтобы выполнять их не в теле цикла, а выполнить один запрос и уже сразу работать с имеющимися данными. Но сделать это у меня не вышло, т.к. запрос всё равно возвращал данные всего по 1 направлению, хотя в базе имелись данные о всех 12. Мой запросы выглядел так:

```
(SELECT ...)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ...)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ...)
```

Как мне сделать множественный SELECT правильно? Хочу получить информацию в виде массива:

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

Comment: JOIN, разве нет?

Comment: @Kyper я никогда не использовал JOIN. И он же вроде нужен для запросов между двумя таблицами?

Comment: ответьте для начала на вопрос, чем не подходит `destination in (все 12 городов)`

Comment: @Мелкий Что это и как его использовать?

Comment: @Мелкий, добавьте как ответ

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [@Мелкий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/203622/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) за наводку. Выполнил запрос с использованием оператора IN:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets_cache WHERE origin = 'MOW' AND destination IN ('LED', 'SIP', 'KHV');
```